# Getting filename, location and author of changed files using RTC source control

Tags: java, clearcase, rtc

I'm trying to access the  filename, location and author of changed files for a given stream. Below code is what I have so far. Looking at the api documentation this does not seem possible? Can this be achieved using the java api or some other method ?

```
        IChangeSetSearchCriteria c = IChangeSetSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
        WorkspaceManager mgr = (WorkspaceManager) SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repo);
        IWorkspaceSearchCriteria criteria = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
        criteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS);
        criteria.setExactName("mystream");
```

Comment: Were you able to get the history for the files? Can you help me with the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: try to not use the Stream name directly, as a Stream can be renamed or another Stream can have the same name.
See [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/40758/searching-for-change-sets-programatically) for more.

> If they're running on the command line, then you can take the UUID of the stream, create a handle from it and set the value in the search criteria (although you may want to fetch the stream first, since the user may have made a typo).

For going from a UUID to an ItemHandle

```
workspaceHandle = (IWorkspaceHandle)IWorkspace.ITEM_TYPE.createItemHandle(workspaceID, null);
```

Regarding listing the content of a changeset, [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/38090/get-files-referred-in-a-change-set-via-rest-apis) provides some clues:

> If the versionable represents a file, it will be an instance of an `IFileItem` which has a content object associated with it.
>   You can get a stream to the contents from the content object.

Again, fetching the changeset (as in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/13789/how-are-previous-change-set-comments-retrieved-using-the-api)) can be key to be sure to get *all* the data.

---

Note: taking the REST API route might be easier:
Your query is a POST

```
Request URL:https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSet?jazz_scm:workspaceId=_OQt98EyrEeGAvYGjhK23_g&jazz_scm:maxResults=25&jazz_scm:changeKind=31
Request Method:POST
Cookie:SaveStateCookie=undefined%2Ccom.ibm.team.workitem.category%2Ccom.ibm.teamz.dsdef.category%2Ccom.ibm.team.dashboard.category%2Ccom.ibm.team.dashboard.category~%23_~%23com.ibm.team.dashboard.server.saveTeamDashboard; JSESSIONID=BF3DA3D5E0FCA16193876307E91A5471; JazzFormAuth=Form; net-jazz-ajax-cookie-rememberUserId=VonC; JSESSIONIDSSO=05626E20EC4F6DB231759EFC4DB69785
Host:jazzServer
Origin:https://jazzServer
Referer:https://jazzServer/jazz/web/projects/My%2°RTC%20Project

Form Dataview URL encoded
{"propertyRequest":{"jazz_scm:lastModified":null,"jazz_scm:creator":{"dcterms:name,rdf:resource":null},"jazz_scm:reasons":{"dcterms:title,rdf:resource":null},"jazz_scm:relatedArtifacts":{"dcterms:title,dcterms:description,rdf:resource,jazz_scm:linkTypeId,oslc_scm:mimeType":null}}}:
```

That will return:

```
{jazz_scm:firstTimestamp:1350975540822, jazz_scm:lastTimestamp:1350285276229,…}
jazz_scm:firstTimestamp: 1350975540822
jazz_scm:lastTimestamp: 1350285276229
jazz_scm:results: [{rdf:resource:https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSetId/__KSygRzVEeK_Q6KSNVybvA,…},…]
    0: {rdf:resource:https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSetId/__KSygRzVDeK_Q6KSNVybvA,…}
    dcterms:description: "Check-in of xslts into RTC taken from UAT server."
    dcterms:identifier: "itemOid/com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet/__KSygRzVDeK_Q6KSNVybvA"
    dcterms:modified: 1350975540822
    dcterms:name: null
    dcterms:type: "com.ibm.team.scm.changeSet"
    jazz_scm:creator: {,…}
        dcterms:description: null
        dcterms:identifier: "itemOid/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor/_YakgYGUUEeCXgMjSYYyTpw"
        dcterms:modified: 1321511726283
        dcterms:name: "a User"
        dcterms:type: "com.ibm.team.scm.contributor"
    jazz_scm:itemId: "_YakgYGUUEeCXgMjSYYyTpw"
    jazz_scm:itemType: "com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor"
    prefixes: {dcterms:http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/, rdf:http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#,…}
    qname: "jazz_scm:Contributor"
    rdf:resource: "https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/itemOid/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor/_YakgYGUUEeCXgMgSYYyTpw"
    jazz_scm:itemId: "__KSygRzVDeK_Q6KSNVybvA"
    jazz_scm:itemType: "com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet"
    jazz_scm:lastModified: null
    jazz_scm:reasons: [{rdf:resource:itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/258061,…}]
    jazz_scm:relatedArtifacts: []
    prefixes: {dcterms:http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/, rdf:http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#,…}
    qname: "oslc_scm:ChangeSet"
    rdf:resource: "https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSetId/__KSygRzVEeK_Q6KSNVybvA"
1: {rdf:resource:https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSetId/_Pg_RMRwzEeK_Q6KSNVybvA,…}
2: {rdf:resource:https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSetId/_3L3gcRwyEeK_Q6KSNVybvA,…}
....
```

With `_OQt98EyrEeGAvYGjhK23_g` the **`workspaceItemId` of the Stream** (a Stream is a Workspace with the element "`stream`" set to true!)

You can get the WorkspaceItemId of a Stream with the following query:

```
Request URL:https://jazzServer/jazz/service/com.ibm.team.scm.common.internal.rest.IScmRestService2/searchWorkspaces?workspaceName=A%20STREAM%20NAME&workspaceNameKind=partial%20ignorecase&maxResultSize=50&workspaceKind=both
Request Method:GET
Cookie:SaveStateCookie=undefined%2Ccom.ibm.team.workitem.category%2Ccom.ibm.teamz.dsdef.category%2Ccom.ibm.team.dashboard.category%2Ccom.ibm.team.dashboard.category~%23_~%23com.ibm.team.dashboard.server.saveTeamDashboard; JSESSIONID=BF3DA3D5E0FCA16193876307E91A5471; JazzFormAuth=Form; net-jazz-ajax-cookie-rememberUserId=VonC; JSESSIONIDSSO=05626E20EC4F6DB231759EFC4DB69785
Host:jazzServer
Referer:https://jazzServer/jazz/web/projects/A%20STREAM%20NAME
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
workspaceName:A STREAM NAME
workspaceNameKind:partial ignorecase
maxResultSize:50
workspaceKind:both
```

That will return results including:

```
<workspaces>
    <workspace itemId="_OQt98EyrEeGAvYGjhK23_g" properties="">
        <stateId>_-flUwBwpEeK_Q6KSNVybvA</stateId>
        <immutable>true</immutable>
        <contextId>_Dp6kMdwTEd2jUupDpEV1Rw</contextId>
        <modified>2012-10-32T10:22:18.766Z</modified>
        <name>A Stream Name</name>
        <stream>true</stream>
        <description>a stream</description>
        <time>109</time>
        <customContext xsi:nil="true"/>
        <normalizedName>a stream name</normalizedName>
        <readPermissionMode>0</readPermissionMode>
        <modifiedBy itemId="_Y70gkCYmEeGAvYGjhJ23_g"/>
        <owner itemId="_ICt_wDL6EeGeLde_4UGHCg" xsi:type="process:ProjectAreaHandle"/>
        <flows>
           ...
```

Comment: the method getVersionable is not implemented in link https://jazz.net/forum/questions/38090/get-files-referred-in-a-change-set-via-rest-apis and I can't find how this might be implemented on the jazz docs. Do you know how getVersionable should be implemented ?

Comment: @user470184 no I don't. I will dig in the Jazz RTC plugin sources tomorrow and see what I can find.

Comment: I think I should try and use the rest API's instead, at least I can sniff the GET request been send via the web client and try and mimc these request problematically, do you think this is a better solution? The java API does not seem very well designed/documented, at least for accessing change set details ?

Comment: @user470184 I agree with the REST API option. See my edited answer for some clues.