# How to retireve all 'changesets' or 'files which are modified' in rtc ccm using oslc scm REST API

Tags: rtc, oslc

Can anyone help me in getting the list of changesets or the files which are modified using oslc. 
Iam using rtc ccm.

Iam able to get it through workitem, but I want to access all changesets directly from scm or any method to get the UUID for all changesets

Comment: There was a previous attempt at https://jazz.net/forum/questions/52871/listing-parts-of-workitem-changeset-with-oslc-xml?redirect=%2Fforum%2Fquestions%2F52871%2Flisting-parts-of-workitem-changeset-with-oslc-xml, but without definitive answer

Comment: I have gone through that but it is dependent on workitems, what I need is I want the changesets directly from scm I got some links but unable to achieve it...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014876/getting-filename-location-and-author-of-changed-files-using-rtc-source-control

Comment: here is the OSLC API uri https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSet?jazz_scm:workspaceId=_OQt98EyrEeGAvYGjhK23_g&jazz_scm:maxResults=25&jazz_scm:changeKind=31 ... I tried it like this         https://******.com/ccm/oslc-scm/changeSet?jazz_scm:workspaceId=_j2tmsBkeEeKzxMDyIEGsFg&jazz_scm:maxResults=25&jazz_scm:changeKind=2"    ... it says   Not  Found

Comment: Hi @VonC, could you please help me out for the above problem, I have followed your post  stackoverflow.com/questions/13014876/.         Iam using jazz ccm so I wrote the url as "https://******.com/ccm/oslc-scm/changeSet?jazz_scm:workspaceId=_j2tmsBkeEeKzxMDyIEGsF‌​g&jazz_scm:maxResults=25" ... it says Not Found

Comment: The only clue I can offer is to try and replicate what you are after in the browser GUI, and see what kind of http request is done (through the Network panel, for instance: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)

Comment: Thanks a ton @VonC It helped it worked, though Iam a new bie here but your clue helped a lot thanks once again and I appreciate your effort for commenting

Comment: If you have found an answer, don't forget you can post it here below, for others to benefit from. Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable on this site.

Comment: Yes @VonC I agree for that but the answer which I got is not using OSLC thing, I got through the clue which you gave any how Im gonna post it... I wanted to try the way you have posted in  stackoverflow.com/questions/13014876.

Answer (score 1):

This url used for achieving the above problem, but I'm not sure it is using OSLC concept in it.

> .com/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.scm.common.internal.rest.IScmRestService2/historyPlus?   n=25&path=workspaceId%2F_Dh7kMAHIEeSZzL8CZgHcOQ%2FcomponentId%2F_j7JnAbl2EeOYP5vHPrH3vA

It returns the change sets without the need of workitem.
if any one find any other (using OSLC & not using API) way please post it here