# How to get the history of a jazz component using oslc

Tags: version-control, rtc, oslc

I have retrieved the component details using
.com/ccm/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.scm.Component/_C8OiATcYEeORAOTpOLW3QQ/?_mediaType=text/xml

then retrieved baseline from above output "" using 
.com/ccm/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.scm.Baseline/_C8hc_DcYEeORAOTpOLW3QQ/?_mediaType=text/xml";

Now I want to retrieve history from above output "" so that I can get the list of all changesets along with the UUIDs...

Can anyone please help me out for this, Im really stuck at this since long time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, URLs of that pattern are not part of Jazz's OSLC interface.

The OSLC interfaces are only part of the Jazz products' REST interfaces - they have product-specific (non-standardized) REST interfaces too, in contrast to the standardized (but less specific) OSLC interfaces.

The way to tell the difference is, if you get the XML representation of the response to a URL, then if it doesn't contain a namespace whose URI includes "open-services.net" then it isn't part of the OSLC interface.

**RTC doesn't support either the [OSLC Software Configuration Management specification](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/ScmSpecV1) nor the later [OSLC Configuration Management work](http://open-services.net/wiki/configuration-management/) and therefore I do not believe it is possible to achieve this using its OSLC interfaces.**

(Sources: jazz.net RTC tickets [Finish/continue OSLC configuration management support](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=213843) and [OSLC SCM catalog entry has wrong URL for oslc_disc:services](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=150073)).

I know this doesn't answer your question as to how to get that information. I do not know if the information is available via the non-OSLC REST API (which you are already looking at). But perhaps this information might help you exclude misleading information (anything about OSLC in your search.)

Also, if you want this to be properly supported in the RTC OSLC API, try commenting on the ticket [Finish/continue OSLC configuration management support](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=213843) stating your desire for this to be implemented.

---

Disclosure/disclaimer: I am an IBM employee, but do not work on the development of Jazz products. My postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent IBM's positions, strategies or opinions.

Comment: Thanks alot @Martin Pain I wanted to confirm the same that OSLC interface does it provide services for SCM or not, but now I'm clear with this post. Any how I have achieved my goal in other way, I just wanted to read the change sets programmatically.

Comment: could you please check here                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014876/getting-filename-location-and-author-of-changed-files-using-rtc-source-control              here the url "https://jazzServer/jazz/oslc-scm/changeSet?jazz_scm:workspaceId=_OQt98EyrEeGAvYGjhK23_g&jazz_scm:maxResults=25&jazz_scm:changeKind=31" giving the list of changesets, when im trying with ccm its failing, could you please tell me what could be the reason