# Getting filtered list of Changesets based on date in jazz

Tags: rtc, jazz

Got up with a new issue, I want to retrieve the filtered list of changesets from jazz based on date, as I got to know OSLC interface does'nt support SCM functionality. So is there any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance
Note: Im not using java plain api

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/a/26864014/6309 clearly explained that OSLC is indeed not possible, I am not sure how you would do such a search *without* using the Java API.

Comment: mmmm yes @VonC as Im new to all this stuff I thought of getting the ways (shortest way) to accomplish a task. Anyways now I have to follow your path (using network tool) and make it done, though it doesn't give the shortest root. Thanks for your quick response and support which helps me in guiding every moment

Comment: @VonC how to perform logout from jazz programatically wihtout using api

Comment: Probably by (programmatically) calling the html url for login out.